# Generic method using instanceof and can it be avoided?

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns, instanceof

I have the following generic interface/classes

```
public interface AnInterface <T>{
    T convertToY();
    String getName();
    String getLastName();
}  

public class Foo implements AnInterface<Foo>{
   // some methods specific to Foo  
}   

public class Bar implements AnInterface<Bar>{
   // some methods specific to Bar
}
```

I created a generic method as follows (I didn't think it would work but it does)

```
public static <T> List<Person> getPersons(AnInterface<T> in) {
        System.out.println(map.get(in));
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (in instanceof Foo) {
            Person p = new Person(in.getName(), in.getLastName());
            p.setId(((Foo) in).getId());
            list.add(p);
        }
        else if(in instanceof Bar) {
            Person p = new Person(in.getName(), in.getLastName());
            p.setCC(((Bar) in).getCC());
            list.add(p);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The issue is that I did not create the classes so I am not sure if doing
`public class Foo implements AnInterface<Foo>` is something usual or not.
So what I am interested in is if there is any issue with the generic method and using `instanceof` and if there is any problems that can be created. E.g. if I recall correctly we can't use `instanceof` on collections so I was wondering if I might make it easy to introduce some other bug with this approach.

**Note:**.
I can't modify `AnInterface` or `Foo` or `Bar`

Comment: `Foo` (as well as `Bar`) is declared as subtype of `AnInterface`, so that the compiler is fine with the downcast, and using the `instanceof` operator makes perfect sense. The only problem is, that your method is hardcoded to those two types. Usually it's better to make use of polymorphism like user tgdavis did in his answer.

Comment: @Mihe: I guess the alternative would be to use some factory pattern to extend for more types? I can't change `AnInterface` as tgdavis suggests. I am sorry I didn't note that in the post

Comment: Yep, a factory could be used as 'poor man's polymorphism'  :-)

Comment: Why returning a list when the list only contain one object?

Comment: @ChengThao: this is a simplified example for clarity of the post. In reality there is a loop and adds more items within the `ifs`

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `applyToPerson` method to `AnInterface`. This ensures that any implementation of `AnInterface` considers what it needs to do in `getPersons`. In your implementation a new subclass of `AnInterface` will result in `getPersons` silently returning an empty list.:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface AnInterface <T>{
    Person applyToPerson(Person p);
    String getName();
    String getLastName();
}

class Person {

    public Person(String name, String lastName) {
        
    }

    void setId(int id) {}
    void setCC(int cc) {}
}

class Foo implements AnInterface<Foo>{
    int getId() { return 0; }
    @Override
    public Person applyToPerson(Person p) {
        p.setId(getId());
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Bar implements AnInterface<Bar>{
    int getCC() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Person applyToPerson(Person p) {
        p.setCC(getCC());
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Application {
    public static List<Person> getPersons(AnInterface in) {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(in.applyToPerson(new Person(in.getName(), in.getLastName())));
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mention it, I can't modify that code

Comment: Which classes can't you modify?

Comment: I can't modify `AnInterface` nor `Foo` nor `Bar`

Comment: Not much you can do other than `instanceof` then, but make sure that the result when a class other than Foo or Bar is passed is what you want: Throw an exception, or add an unmodified Person to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the type specific operation into a parameter. E.g.

```java
public static <T extends AnInterface<T>>
    List<Person> getPersons(T in, BiConsumer<T, Person> setup) {

    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Person p = new Person(in.getName(), in.getLastName());
    setup.accept(in, p);
    list.add(p);
    return list;
}
```

This moves the responsibility to the caller or, if they also don’t know the actual type of `T`, to their callers.

```java
Foo f = new Foo();
List<Person> persons = getPersons(f, (in, p) -> p.setId(in.getId()));
```

```java
Bar b = new Bar();
List<Person> persons = getPersons(b, (in, p) -> p.setCC(in.getCC()));
```

You could also provide overloads, so callers knowing the exact type do not require the second parameter

```java
public static List<Person> getPersons(Foo in) {
    return getPersons(in, (foo, p) -> p.setId(foo.getId()));
}

public static List<Person> getPersons(Bar in) {
    return getPersons(in, (bar, p) -> p.setCC(bar.getCC()));
}
```

But generic callers would still require the other method and have to move the responsibility for providing the operator to their callers…

---

What’s puzzling, is the existence of the `convertToY()` method in the interface and the original declaration of the parameter type as `AnInterface<T>`. Maybe, the intention behind this design was using something like

```java
public static <T>
    List<Person> getPersons(AnInterface<T> in, BiConsumer<T, Person> setup) {

    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Person p = new Person(in.getName(), in.getLastName());
    setup.accept(in.convertToY(), p);
    list.add(p);
    return list;
}
```

But for the code as given in the question, it has no advantage. The caller will look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo implements AnInterface<Foo>{...}
```

Maybe the code works, but what is the meaning of this? It's unclear, since the foo class doesn't have an implementation yet.

```
public class Foo implements AnInterface<T>{...}
```

This is not your case, but a more generic version, so still interesting. A non-generic class that extends a generic one. Seems it's considered an antipattern.
[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243478/is-there-ever-justification-for-the-pseudo-typedef-antipattern)

Comment: As `Foo` is not declared abstract, it _has_ to have an implementation of `AnInterface<Foo>`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little you can do, if you're not allowed to modify these classes and interface.

Since you've taken such route that implementations of `Foo` and `Bar` diverged from another, and you can't interoperate between them, I would advise splitting this method into two independent well-readable overloaded methods:

```
public static List<Person> getPersons(Bar bar) {
    
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Person p = new Person(bar.getName(), bar.getLastName());
    p.setCC(bar.getCC());
    list.add(p);
    
    return list; // use List.of(p) if you don't need this list be modifiable
}

public static List<Person> getPersons(Foo foo) {
    
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Person p = new Person(foo.getName(), foo.getLastName());
    p.setId(foo.getId());
    list.add(p);
    
    return list; // use List.of(p) if you don't need this list be modifiable
}
```

In case if you want to keep a single method expecting an instance of the super type, these one small enhancement I can suggest.

Instead of performing casting after `instanceof`-check you can make use of the [*Pattern Matching for instanceof*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html) which was introduced with Java 16.

```
if (in instanceof Foo foo) {
    Person p = new Person(foo.getName(), foo.getLastName());
    p.setId(foo.getId());
    list.add(p);
}
```