# Inner class does not have access to <T> of the outer interface

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to follow the approach given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173946/factory-pattern-using-a-hashmap-and-functional-approach) of my earlier question:
But the code does not compile:

```
public interface Processor <T> {
     class Builder {
        private T t = null;  // assign default values
        private String firstName = null;
        private String lastName = null;
        private String cc = null;
    }
    List<Person> process();
}
```

I get the error

```
com.foo.Processor.this can not be referenced from a static context
```

How can I make the code compile so I can try out the approach of that answer?

Comment: (BTW that is not an *inner class*, just a *nested class* - Java Language Specification [8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3-120): "The following nested classes are implicitly `static`, so are not *inner* classes: ... - a member class of an interface" - and since `static`, you have no `T` type for it {at least not the one from the interface})

Comment: *How can I make the code compile* -> Make `Builder` also generic -> `Builder<T>`.

Comment: you need to show the _entire_ `Processor` (what is and where is `Person`?) and also exactly how you get that error.

Comment: using previous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74177639/inner-class-does-not-have-access-to-t-of-the-outer-interface#comment130965638_74177639) (from Lino): be aware that `Builder<T>` is using a different `T` than the one of the interface (recommended to use a different type name)

Comment: Why do you even try this approach if it doesn’t even address your (previous) question?

Comment: @Holger: I didn't realise that it won't help until I started trying it. I couldn't understand the answer initially and wanted to try it out in case it started to make sense

Answer (score 2):

`Processor` is not a class, it's an interface. Nested classes in interfaces are `static` by default.

But the builder does not define any logic. Move the builder to the implementation (classes) of the interface.

```
public class RealProcessor<T> implements Processor<T> {
     class Builder {
        private T t = null;  // assign default values
        private String firstName = null;
        private String lastName = null;
        private String cc = null;
    }
    List<Person> process();
}
```

Comment: The `Builder` does have logic it is just that I showed the part that does not compile. If you check the answer linked in my post you can see the builder logic

Comment: @Jim the linked answer does not compiler. You cannot `new` an interface. The nested `Builder` class has no relation to the enclosing interface; they are unrelated. If you must, you can make `Builder` generic itself (but its T will be different from Processor's T)

Comment: Consider adding JLS sources per user16320675's first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make static class `Builder` generic if it is declared inside the interface:

```
public interface Processor <T> {
    class Builder<T> {
       private T t = null;
       // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Note that as `Builder` is a static class the name of the generic does not need to be `<T>`, this is an equivalent declaration using `<X>`:

```
public interface Processor <T> {
    class Builder<X> {
       private X t = null;
       // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

The instantiation for both is same without need to qualify `Processor` generic type:

```
Builder<SomeClass> builder = new Processor.Builder<SomeClass>(arg, ... );
```